# How to map NFS client root user to NFS server root user?

Tags: linux, nfs

We have a problem when using NFS. We can't write into a directory on NFS client machine if that directory was created on NFS server. The reason seems to be a file/directory permission and user mapping.

**Our setup:**

We have 2 EC2 nodes - Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

NFS server installed on one machine:

```
ubuntu@master:~$ less /etc/exports
/home/ubuntu/data *(rw,no_subtree_check,sync,insecure)
```

The same dir is mounted on another machine:

```
sudo mkdir /home/ubuntu/data
sudo mount -t nfs masterIp:/home/ubuntu/data /home/ubuntu/data
```

**A problem we have:**

When we create a dir in NFS in a master it's created like this:

```
# sudo mkdir /home/ubuntu/data/Test
# sudo ls -all /home/ubuntu/data
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root       4096 Jul  5 07:19 Test
```

Master has no issues accessing this directory, creating file insideeetc. But when we try to create a file from a slave node inside of Test dir, we have got Permission denied error.

When we create a dir from a NFS client machine it looks like this:

```
# sudo mkdir /home/ubuntu/data/Test2
# sudo ls -all /home/ubuntu/data
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root       4096 Jul  5 07:19 Test
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody nogroup   4096 Jul  5 07:21 Test2
```

So it seems NFS client's root user is mapped to nobody@nogroup when writing to NFS directories and thus can't write to directories created by root user on NFS server.
We need to map a NFS clinet's root user to NFS server's root user so both of them can work freely with directories no matter where they we created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `no_root_squash` option in your `/etc/exports` entry. From the manual page for `exports`:

> User ID Mapping
>
> nfsd bases its access control to files on the server machine on the
>   uid and gid provided in each NFS RPC request. The normal behavior a
>   user would expect is that she can access her files on the server just
>   as she would on a normal file system. This requires that the same uids
>   and gids are used on the client and the server machine. This is not
>   always true, nor is it always desirable.
>
> Very often, it is not desirable that the root user on a client machine
>   is also treated as root when accessing files on the NFS server. To
>   this end, *uid 0 is normally mapped to a different id: the so-called
>   anonymous or **nobody** uid*. This mode of operation (called 'root
>   squashing') is the default, and can be turned off with `no_root_squash`.